# Extract only keys from URL

Tags: c++, regex

I am receiving url as ( I am using c++, not c++11 and cannot use boost neither )

```
fbconnect://success?request=1658882854368553&to%5B0%5D=10207704056262807
```

where keys can be other than `request` ( like `error_code` ).
I need to extract only keys, how to do that with regex ?
At the moment I split first by `?` and than by `&` and than by `=` but I wonder is there shorter way to achieve this ?

Comment: Regex isn't available before c++11.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Maybe she's using a different regex lib...

Comment: if you want a regex then I think `&(.+?)=` will work, but it will only match the first result and you will need to apply it on the remaining part, so you will have to do something like `&(.+?)=.+?(&.*)`, take the first group as a result and reapply the same expression over the second group, this will definitely not be faster, your method is ok

Answer (score 1):

Following regular expression will capture all query string field names:

```
[\?&]([^=]+)=
```

This is probably shorter than

> At the moment I split first by ? and than by & and than by =

But consider which is more readable. Usually readability is more important than length of code. Also, it might be overkill to include a regular expression engine if you don't need it for anything else.